# Dot symbol in set-builder expressions in CRDT literature?

Tags: distributed-systems, concurrency, notation

In [*Conflict-free Replicated Data Types: An Overview*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.10254.pdf) and other CRDT-related publications by Preguiça's group, a dot symbol often appears without definition. What does it indicate, how standard is it as notation, and what field's literature does it come from? For example:

$$\{ v \mid \mathrm{wr}(v) \in O \land \nexists \mathrm{wr}(u) \in O \cdot \mathrm{wr}(v) \prec \mathrm{wr}(u) \}$$

In context, it seems like some kind of nested "such that," but I'm only starting to read this literature and want to be sure.

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible, e.g., to provide a citation with title, authors, and where it was published.  This will help others with a similar question about this paper to find this page via search.  I encourage you to take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!